# Opening multiple instances of a MS access file?

Tags: microsoft-access, multiple-instances, mdb

is there a way to simultaneously 2 or more instances of the same MS access file on one computer? I need to do diff things on the same database.

Thanks a lot.

Tam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Just open two instances of access by clicking the icon to start Access instead of clicking the database file itself. Then within each instance of Access open the Database from the file menu.

Comment: i forgot to mention, copying the .mdb file isn't an option. sorry.

Comment: I didn't mean to copy the database, I meant open two instances of Access.